# Is there something like readonly property for a dropdown?

Tags: php, select

My form contains a radio-button & a drop-down. So depending upon the selected value of radio button i need to enable/disable the drop-down.

I am doing this:

```
<select name="bas_type" id="bas_type" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
  <option value="Annualy">Annualy</option>
</select>
```

But i want to get drop-down value as empty in $_POST if form is disabled..
So this won't work. Please any suggestions..

Comment: Seems unnecessary, just have an if statement in your php if the selected radio button value enabled the drop down then do some work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a hidden field with the value you want to receive when the control is disabled and the same name as the dropdown. Be sure to place it **before** the dropdown in the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="bas_type" value="" />
<select name="bas_type" id="bas_type" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
  <option value="Annualy">Annualy</option>
</select>
```

Of course you shouldn't really have to do this, since in PHP you should be receiving incoming parameters with at least a helper function like

```
function param($name, $default = null) {
    return isset($_REQUEST[$name]) ? $_REQUEST[$name] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the value in the form to "" and that should do the trick:

```
<option value="">Annualy</option>
```

or use a space like this (not sure which will work better for you, haven't tried to do it):

```
<option value=" ">Annualy</option>
```

Edit: The data contained in the `value="something"` is the actual data that is passed to the URL via a get. Hence, if you blank it out, the data won't get passed.

Comment: but how will this solves my problem..?? Sorry i did not get it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on data you get from form. What you should actually do is check serverside if radiobutton is active or not, and depending on that ignore or accept value from dropbox.

Comment: i have a dynamic form i.e the form contains all dynamic fields..i cant do it manually.. server side check.